# How do I make a panda frames values across multiple columns, its columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe loaded up in Pandas.

`print(pandaDf)`

`id    col1    col2    col3
12a       a       b       d
22b       d       a       b
33c       c       a       b`

I am trying to convert the values across multiple rows into its columns so the output would be like this :

Desired output:

`id     a   b   c   d
12a     1   1   0   1
22b     1   1   0   0
33c     1   1   1   0`

I have tried adding in a value column where the value = 1 and using a pivot table

`pandaDf['value'] = 1
column = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
pandaDf.pivot_table(index = 'id', value = 'value', columns = column)`

However, the resulting data frame is a multilevel index and the pandaDf.pivot() method does not allow multiple column values.

Please advise about how I could do this with an output of a single level index.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I apologize if I have made any formatting errors in posting the question. I am still learning the proper stackoverflow syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can use One-Hot Encoding to solve this problem.
Here is one way to do this `pd.get_dummies` and some multiindex flatten and `sum`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')
df_out = pd.get_dummies(df1)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df_out = df_out.sum(level=1, axis=1).reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    id  a  c  d  b
0  12a  1  0  1  1
1  22b  1  0  1  1
2  33c  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: Guess join will work here, df.set_index('id').apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies().reset_index()

Comment: @vaishali You should submit that as a answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott, this is perfect. I have used dummies before but I would never have imagined using it for this :)

Comment: @NischalReddy I think Wen's solution is more elegant than mine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id'),prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[81]: 
     a  c  d  b
id             
12a  1  0  1  1
22b  1  0  1  1
33c  1  1  0  1
```